# Nonlinear WPF Slider values

Tags: wpf, xaml, slider

It is straightforward to remap the linear values returned by a WPF slider control:

```
public double Multiplier
{
  get
  {
    switch ((int)sliderMultiplier.Value)
    {
      case 0: return 0.1;
      case 1: return 0.2;
      case 2: return 0.5;
      case 3: return 1;
      case 4: return 2;
      case 5: return 5;
      case 6: return 10;
      default: throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
    }
  }
}
```

But the slider handle, while being dragged, is accompanied by a tooltip showing the selected value - the unmapped linear value. How can I supply the remapped value for display? Or get the slider to supply non-linear values directly?

Comment: http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2007/09/14/modifying-the-auto-tooltip-of-a-slider/

Comment: Post the link as an answer and I'll accept it. It works but OMG that's so hacky!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somebody else has solved this (as far as the tooltips are concerned). Couldn't find a way of having the slider itself actually report a non-linear value range.

http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2007/09/14/modifying-the-auto-tooltip-of-a-slider/

Comment: It works, which is a great deal better than nothing. The fact that it's such an ugly hack may motivate me to build a better slider, probably one with a remap event. That wouldn't be such a bad outcome, so thank you very much!